# Basic security for a kiosk?

Tags: security, kiosk

I am very new to Raspberry Pi anything, and have just set up a kiosk. What do I need to know about security?

Our network (I'm a public librarian) has a firewall and the usual security, but is there anything that needs to happen on the Pi itself to secure things?

Comment: This would represent a good start: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1247/what-should-be-done-to-secure-raspberry-pi/3497#3497. I can expand on this if you would like since I teach a class on python and physical computing at my local library.

Comment: Thank you! Looks manageable for now, but I will certainly be back as needed

Comment: Don't forget physical security? the Pi is easily stolen and if they can access the SD card they could display anything on your kiosk - I will leave the possibilities to your imagination.