# Automatic clean of unattended upgrades

Tags: apt, operating-systems, update

Following the [Debian wiki documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades) and [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/72022/configuring-unattended-upgrades-on-raspbian-stretch) I have successfully set up unattended upgrades. I have confirmed that upgrades are really run.

However, I want to avoid eventually getting disk space problems, so I want to make sure that `apt clean` is also run regularly.

The Debian documentation seems to imply that I need create a file at `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02periodic` and add something like this to it

```
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "21";
```

But I haven't needed any of the other settings suggested for that file (such as `APT::Periodic::Enable "1"`).

I find the wiki page really confusing. It suggests two completely different ways of configuring when to run unattended upgrades: *Automatic call via /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02periodic* and *Modifying download and upgrade schedules (on systemd)*, but gives no indication when or why you would use one or the other. I've used the latter way, since that seemed simplest.

`/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily-upgrade.timer` (which is definitely run) clearly states

```
Description=Daily apt upgrade and clean activities
```

Note the *`and clean`*.

So, will I get automatic `apt clean` without creating a `02periodic`, or not?

Comment: This is a general Debian question and has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I'm new to both Raspberry Pi and Debian, so it is quite possible that I have misclassified my question, but it depends on what the answer is. One could have assumed that unattended upgrades themselves would be identical in Debian and Raspberry Pi, but they are not, which can be seen in one of the answers that I refer to in my question.

Comment: I think that the answer to my question is "no". You have to do the following, since autoclean is not turned on by default: 
`echo 'APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "7";' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades`

Comment: Please make your comment an answer. This will finish the question and show others that it has a solution. After two days you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the answer to my question is "no".

You have to do the following, since `autoclean` is not turned on by default:

```
echo 'APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "7";' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades
```

I have confirmed that this causes cleanup of files in `/var/cache/apt/archives/` that would otherwise have been left there.