# Configuring/scheduling weekly updates for RPi 3

Tags: update

So I've been reading across the web on this, but can't find a good guide on how to set this up. I gave my parent's a Raspberry Pi 3 that I have installed pi-hole and zerotier on to give them some network wide ad-blocking, as well as giving me a VPN tunnel into their network so I can do remote troubleshooting if necessary.

I'm trying to figure out a way to schedule automatic updates for this pi to happen on a weekly basis (ie. Monday morning at like 4:00AM), so that it updates overnight when no-one is online since it is their DNS resolver. I want all 3 of the base OS, Pi-Hole, and the zerotier client to get updated. Looks like I should be able to install unattended-upgrades on the system to do it with, but figuring out how to set the schedule as I want is confusing me.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Another option is to install and configure `unattended-upgrades`. Unless you have PPAs setting it up is not that difficult.

Comment: FWIW: I looked into this once. I decided against it for one simple reason: the *reboot* function in unattended upgrades ***did not work***. IIRC, it was broken/failed in Ubuntu & Debian, and not even implemented in RPi. Since upgrades often require a reboot, this means that automatic or unattended upgrades must also include a reboot - whether it's required or not. Failure to reboot when required will occasionally leave your system in a state of chaos.

Comment: @Seamus You can roll your own reboot script and use cron to schedule it. [I did it for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009007/unattended-upgrades-pending-reboot-prevents-shutdown-from-user/1009096#1009096) and it works fine in RasPi OS.

Comment: @user68186: Of course you can. But if `unattended-upgrades` isn't capable of determining if a reboot is required, what is the point, exactly?

Comment: @Seamus `unattended upgrades` creates a file if reboot is required, and it gets deleted on reboot. The existence of that file in RPi shows that the app is "capable of determining if reboot is required" There are use cases where you may not want a server to reboot automatically, but continue to run until it is convenient to reboot. See my answer below for an alternate method of automatic reboot when needed.

Comment: @user68186: I don't think `unattended-upgrades` is a good idea - certainly it's not for me personally. This opinion is based on a risk-reward comparison for my RPi use-case. I'm just not that bothered to spend a few minutes every week or so to manually update & upgrade. YMMV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Caution

Setting up automatic updates can lead to broken system. If this happens and the Pi does not boot (after an attempted reboot) the next update won't fix the problem. It has happened to me.

The best practice is to wait a week or two after an update is released to make sure there are no show-stopper bugs or regressions. This is not possible if you use unattended upgrade.

You may want to make periodic disk images as backups in an attached USB drive. This way you can restore the MicroSD card from the image file using another computer and the Imager app.

## Install `unattended-upgrades`

Open a terminal and enter the command:

```
sudo apt install unattended-upgrades
```

The default setting will look for updates every night and install them.

## Basic Configuration

Edit the file: `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` uncomment (remove //) or add the following lines

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern {
        "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename}-updates";
        "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian";
        "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian-Security";
        "origin=Raspbian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Raspbian";
        "origin=Raspberry Pi Foundation,codename=${distro_codename},label=Raspberry Pi Foundation";
};
```

The last two lines with `Raspbian` and `Raspberry Pi` are the most important ones. I am not sure if you need the `Debian` ones. I have them and so far I have not had any issues. YMMV.

### Autoremove

To set up autoremove, look for these lines in the above file:

```
// Do automatic removal of unused packages after the upgrade
// (equivalent to apt-get autoremove)
//Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "false";
```

Uncomment the third line above and make it look like:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "true";
```

### Reboot if needed

Periodically updates need restarting the Pi to take effect. This is particularly true for kernel updates. look for these lines in the above file:

```
// Automatically reboot *WITHOUT CONFIRMATION* if
//  the file /var/run/reboot-required is found after the upgrade
//Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "false";
```

Uncomment the third line above and make it look like:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";
```

If you want to reboot the Pi at a fixed time at night, such as at 2:00 AM only if a reboot is needed look for these lines

```
// If automatic reboot is enabled and needed, reboot at the specific
// time instead of immediately
//  Default: "now"
//Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "02:00";
```

Uncomment the fourth line above and make it look like:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "02:00";
```

Note: Some have said that reboot does not work in `unattended-upgrades`. If you find this is the case, see a workaround below under the **Advanced Configuration**.

Reference: https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-enable-configure-unattended-upgrades-on-debian-11/

Also see [Configuring `unattended-upgrades` on Raspbian Stretch](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/72022/configuring-unattended-upgrades-on-raspbian-stretch/74973#74973)

## Advanced Configuration

### Reduce Upgrade Frequency

Upgrade takes place every morning by the default configuration. To change it to weekly upgrade, edit the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades`:

```
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "7";
```

Note, `unattended-upgades` does not allow for setting a specific day, such as Monday, for the upgrade. The "7" above sets the interval of upgrades to 7 days.

### Change the upgrade time of the day

The default time of unattended upgrade is randomly set between 6 and 7 AM. The default randomization is needed so that every computer using this app do not overload the upgrade repositories by trying to get updates exactly at the same time.

To set the upgrade time to 4:00 AM, use the following command to create the file `/etc/systemd/system/apt-daily-upgrade.timer.d/override.conf`:

```
sudo systemctl edit apt-daily-upgrade.timer
```

This will open a blank file if none exists. Enter the following lines:

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar=
OnCalendar=04:00
RandomizedDelaySec=0
```

Save and exit the editor. See the [Debian documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades) for the explanation.

### Add Other Repositories

So far `unattended-upgrades` is configured to upgrade applications that exist only in the official repositories. Sometimes we install software that are in special repositories not included in the default system.

I have no experience with Pi-Hole, and the Zerotier. As far as I can tell Pi-Hole does not use the `apt` system for upgrade. As a result it cannot be (easily) included in the `unattended-upgrades` configuration.

As far as I can tell Zerotier adds a PPA in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/zerotier.list` The line in that file looks like something like:

```
http://download.zerotier.com/debian/RELEASE RELEASE main
```

Where RELEASE is the OS nickname, maybe buster or bullseye for Pi.

You would like to add a **origin** and **archive** to the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`. To find what those are for your PPAs open the folder `/var/lib/apt/lists/`, that is the storage area for state information for each package resource. What you are looking for is the files that begins with "Zerotier" and ends with "Release" in the name.

**As I don't have Zerotier, I will give the example of "Google Chrome"**

Open one with your text editor, ie for Google Chrome:

```
sudo nano /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_Release
```

You will see something like:

```
Origin: Google, Inc. 
Label: Google 
Suite: stable 
Codename: stable 
Version: 1.0 
Date: Thu, 17 Nov 2011 19:09:01 +0000 Architectures: i386 amd64 
Components: main 
Description: Google chrome-linux repository.
```

The origin is obvious (Origin: Google, Inc.) and the archive will be whatever is in the line Suite (Suite: stable).

If either Origin or Suite is missing then they will be the empty string. But note that if both are missing then probably it will not be possible to use that source with unattended upgrades without including other sources with the same issue.

After you noted those 2 lines you need to edit the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` file and add the lines using this format `"o=<origin>,a=<archive>";` for this example’s sake:

```
"o=Google Inc.,a=stable";
```

See commented out similar lines in the file to determine where the above line should go.

### Reboot using `crontab`

Some have reported that automated reboot configuration in `unattended-upgrades` do not work as intended. If that is the case you may want to use a bash script and `crontab` to reboot the Pi if and when needed by `unattended-upgrade`.

#### Stop Unattended-Upgrades from restarting the computer

Right now Unattended-Upgrades is setup to restart the computer at 2:00AM if the update requires a restart. This step will stop this behavior.

**Step:** edit the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`

Inside the file look for the line:

```
unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";
```

and make it look like:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "false";
```

#### Create a bash script to check if restart is required and do it if needed

The script below checks if the file `reboot-required` exists and if so, it reboots the computer immediately. Let's call this file `reboot_if_needed.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]; then
        echo $(date) Sytem restart required by: $(cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs)
        /sbin/reboot now
fi
```

Save this file as `/opt/bin/reboot_if_needed.sh`

Make this file executable:

```
sudo chmod +x `/opt/bin/reboot_if_needed.sh`
```

**Explanation**

When the script runs and the file `var/run/reboot-required` exists it will output some text that will be captured in a log file `/var/log/reboot_history.log`. Then the system will restart.

#### Schedule `reboot_if_needed.sh` every night at 2:00 AM

Note, even though script is to run every night, the Pi will not be rebooted every night. It will be rebooted only when it is required by the upgrade.

We want to run the script with administrator privileges. So we use `sudo`:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

This command will open the crontab file for the root user if one exists, or create a blank new file. Add the following line at the end of the file:

```
0 02 * * * /opt/bin/reboot_if_needed.sh >> /var/log/reboot_history.log
```

Save the file and exit the text editor.

For more details on rebooting with `crontab` for `unattended-upgrades` see [this answer in Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009007/unattended-upgrades-pending-reboot-prevents-shutdown-from-user/1009096#1009096)

I have `unattended-upgrade` running for about a year in Buster, and a few weeks in Bullseye. Once my system got screwed up by a bad update. Otherwise it has been working fine.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for all this. In the end, I decided that I was going to roll my own with a simple script, as I want specific control over day and time that using unattended-upgrade wouldn't provide (I get I could edit the daily timer file, but it just seems wrong to edit a file named "daily" to not be). But this did give me a of source information I used, and learned a ton, so thanks.

Comment: @EvanM. You are welcome. Rolling your own gives you more control and I am all for it if it works for you. Writing this answer helped me decide to make a few changes in my unattended upgrade config as well. Hopefully this answer will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

There are automatic update programs such as `unattended-upgrades`, but I have never used one.

Upgrading the Pi is a hazardous undertaking; it usually works, but occasionally it causes corrupted OS. There are many reports on this site, and it has happened to me a few times. It appears that many are caused by ageing SD Cards, which have a limited life.

As a consequence my upgrade process is to **first** BACKUP then upgrade.

Bullseye does have `apt-daily-upgrade` (at least in the Desktop version) but AFAIK this is just a notification of available updates, which need to be manually initiated. It appears to run at ~0600.