# What should I do to insulate other computers on the network from my Raspberry Pi?

Tags: networking, security

I am going to host a small server for small text-based webservice on a RPI as I dont have funds for a remote server. Someone might pehaps try to hack it someday, and as I am only a hobbyist, I assume we are in a scenario where the hacker has access to the whole RPI.

So, **how do I make it difficult for the attacker to get access to my other devices and router on the system?**. Like, what security practices should I incorporate? Like for instance use a vpn, proxy or something like that?

I have read this thread also:
[What should be done to secure Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1247/what-should-be-done-to-secure-raspberry-pi?rq=1)

*I am thinking about running a spring-boot and some SQL program using an ordinary user account (no root privelages) with write and read permissions.*

Comment: The Pi is a computer. Do exactly what you would do for any other computer. If hackers can reach your Pi you have already failed.

Comment: This is not a Pi-specific question... Should have been posted somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

Put the Pi in a DMZ.

You can create a DMZ by adding a second router

```
                               +----+
                               | Pi |
                               +----+
  (---------)    +-------+        |       +--------+        (----------)
(  internal  )---|router1|----------------| router2|-------(  Internet  )
 (  network )    +-------+                +--------+         (----------)
   (-------)
```

On router 2 you enable the portforwarding to the Pi, on router 1 you do not enable any portforwarding. This effectively protects the internal network from the Pi as much as it was usually protected from the Internet.

Of course, the Pi requires a bit more attention, being exposed to the outside world. Keep everything up-to-date, remove all software that is not required, and review the logs regularly.