# How do I set up ssh keys to log into my RPi

Tags: ssh

Using ssh keys to log into your RPi is much more convenient than typing the password everytime.

It's especially handy if you want to log in from automated scripts or use programs such as scp or rsync

So how do I set up ssh keys to log into my RPi?

Comment: Very similar question/answer [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/508/40).

Comment: And here:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66613/how-can-i-use-scp-ssh-in-a-cron-script-without-entering-a-password?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 16):

## Linux

If you've never heard of ssh-keys before, you'll need to generate one like this

```
$ ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

This creates a directory `~/.ssh/` and stores the key files

```
$ ls -l .ssh/
-rw------- 1 gnibbler gnibbler 668 Aug 22  2004 .ssh/id_dsa
-rw------- 1 gnibbler gnibbler 603 Aug 22  2004 .ssh/id_dsa.pub
```

You need to copy `id_dsa.pub` to the RPi. There is a very easy way to do this using a helper script.

```
$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub pi@raspberrypi.local
```

You'll need to type the `pi` user password one last time

Next time you log in, you won't be prompted for a password

```
$ ssh pi@raspberrypi.local
Linux raspberrypi 3.1.9+ #174 PREEMPT Sun Jul 22 19:04:28 BST 2012 armv6l

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.

Type 'startx' to launch a graphical session
```

### How do I disable password logins?

Once you have set up key-based logins, you don't need to log in using a password anymore; you can disable it, which is much more secure.

1. First, log in to your Raspberry Pi and open `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` as `root`; for example, run `sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config`.
2. Find the line containing `PasswordAuthentication`; it probably reads `#PasswordAuthentication yes`.
3. Change this line so it reads

   PasswordAuthentication no
4. Restart your Raspberry Pi, or just `sshd`.

#### Arch Linux

To restart `sshd` on Arch, run `sudo rc.d restart sshd`.

#### Debian/Raspbian

To restart `sshd` on Debian based distributions, run `sudo /etc/init.d/sshd restart`.

Comment: Please be aware that password-less ssh should only be used where you know the connection is already **secure**. Otherwise you are putting yourself at risk to save 10 seconds.

Comment: @Jivings Explain? Keys are always more secure than passwords.

Comment: @gnibbler Would you accept an edit on how to disable password logins?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain, of course

Comment: @AlexChamberlain This answer says how to set up password-less keys. That's to what I was referring

Comment: @Jivings O I see, but that's nothing to do with the connection. Passworded keys are decrypted locally.

Comment: @jivings and gnibbler: The Debian restarting `sshd` needs to be checked; it might be `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart`.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain The encryption strength is reduced. And if a key is compromised then they can be easily used. All I'm saying is that you are sacrificing a layer of security for the sake of a few seconds